# looking for non-overlapping community detection algorithm with lower time complexity

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, networkx, graph-theory, network-analysis

I am trying to find community in a simple undirected network. I am looking for algorithm as well as code with lower time complexity than Clauset-Newman-Moore(CNM) algorithm. I tried to search but I couldn't find, please guide me here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [Leiden](https://github.com/vtraag/leidenalg) algorithm, it's a faster implementation of the Louvain algorithm with a smaller chance of returning poorly connected/disconnected communities.